# Google manual search results do not match Custom Search API results

Tags: google-api-client, google-apis-explorer

I am trying to obtain the total result count from manual Google web search via the CustomSearch API. I am searching the entire web based on a keyword and an associated site, so the search query is " site:". Judging by my research, it is a known issue that manual Google search results tend to differ from CustomSearch API results obtained from searching the entire web, as cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37652178/9450453) and elsewhere.

Is there really no way to exactly reproduce manual search results with the API? If that is the case, then the API is rather limited and should be explained up-front to developers in the documentation or fixed.

My custom search engine is already set up to search the whole web I believe.

[image: Custom Search Engine Console]

It looks like maybe PDF files returned in a web search are not returned by the API. I have already tried specifying fileType parameter to include PDFs to no avail.

[image: Google Web Search]
3 Results returned via manual web search.

[image: APIs Explorer - CustomSearch]
[image: Results]
0 results returned by API.

If anyone has lessons to share I will be thankful!